# In a banking organization, why would account balance be declared as varchar and not decimal?

Tags: datatypes, varchar

I worked in two organizations where I found money related columns are defined as `VARCHAR` data type. I didn't get correct explanation from anyone. As the database team is totally isolated with our team.

Is there any specific purpose for defining the amount, account balance, money in `varchar` datatype?

Comment: No, we would only ever define money as a varchar if we were loading data to a staging table

Answer (score 1):

We do this in our data warehouse. It's because decimal has a fixed precision and float isn't accurate past a certain number of decimal places. We need to retain the most accurate value extracted from the source as we are summing over 100 million rows and the rounding would put our figures out. However if you've got a fixed number of decimal places, then go for a decimal datatype or similar.